# Fractional Brownian Motion's Covariance Proof

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, finance-mathematics, stochastic-volatility

Let's have the non independent Brownian motion such :

$B_{H}(r)=\frac{1}{A(H)} \int_{R}\left[\left\{(r-s)_{+}\right\}^{H-1 / 2}-\left\{(-s)_{+}\right\}^{H-1 / 2}\right] \mathrm{d} B(s), \quad r \in R$

Rewriting it as(For $r2 > r1 $) :

$\begin{aligned}
B_{H}(r)=& \frac{1}{A(H)} \int_{-\infty}^{0}\left\{(r-s)^{H-1 / 2}-(-s)^{H-1 / 2}\right\} \mathrm{d} B(s) \\
&+\frac{1}{A(H)} \int_{0}^{r}(r-s)^{H-1 / 2} \mathrm{~d} B(s)
\end{aligned}$

$E((B_H(r2) - B_H(r1))^2) = E(\frac{1}{A(H)^2} (\int_{-\infty}^{0}\left\{(r2-s)^{H-1 / 2}-(r1-s)^{H-1 / 2}\right\} \mathrm{d} B(s) \\) + \int_{0}^{r1}\left\{(r2-s)^{H-1 / 2}-(r1-s)^{H-1 / 2}\right\} \mathrm{d} B(s) + \int_{r1}^{r2}\left\{(r2-s)^{H-1 / 2}\right\} \mathrm{d} B(s))^2)$

Trough Ito's isometry we have :

$\implies  \frac{1}{A(H)^2} (\int_{-\infty}^{r1}\left\{(r2-s)^{H-1 / 2}-(r1-s)^{H-1 / 2}\right\}^2 \mathrm{d} s \\)+ \int_{r1}^{r2}\left\{(r2-s)^{2H -1}\right\} \mathrm{d} s))$

$\implies  \frac{1}{A(H)^2} (\int_{-\infty}^{r1}\left\{(r2-s)^{H-1 / 2}-(r1-s)^{H-1 / 2}\right\}^2 \mathrm{d} s \\)+ \frac{(r2-r1)^{2H}}{2H})$

How can we rewrite the first integral,using a variable change such :

$\frac{1}{A(H)^2} (\int_{-\infty}^{r1}\left\{(r2-s)^{H-1 / 2}-(r1-s)^{H-1 / 2}\right\}^2 \mathrm{d} s \\)+ \frac{(r2-r1)^{2H}}{2H})$

becomes  :

$\frac{(r2-r1)^{2H}}{A(H)^2} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{0}\left((1-u)^{H-\frac{1}{2}}-(u)^{H-\frac{1}{2}}\right)^{2} d u+\frac{1}{2 H}\right)$

Thank you for your help.

**(For brevity I considered $r2 > r1$,which may not always be the case in a covariance matrix )